# ffcast and compton - a shadowy problem

Tags: ffmpeg, shadow, compton

So I have compton, a composite manager that I use to make things look prettier, mostly to add *shadows* to windows, and make things transparent.

I also have `ffcast`, which I currently am using to make gifs or mp4s by selecting a part of my screen and recording it.

The two don't seem to mix well however, as if I start recording with compton being enabled...

[image: Whoops]

This happens! The entire region is covered by a shadow! I'm sure this is caused by compton, but I have some problems. Firstly, I'm not too sure how the `shadow-exclude` option works in compton, apart that if you add something like:

`shadow-exclude = ["class_g = 'something'"];`

...it will avoid displaying shadows on all applications which have the `WM_CLASS` 'something'.

I can find the WM_CLASS of any window using `xprop WM_CLASS` however which should make things easier, however, this **does not work with the shadowy region** as it just selects whatever it is covering.

So I am at a loss. I'm not sure whether this is a bug that's possible to fix or what, but I cannot find a way to remove this shadow apart from turning off compton completely or removing shadows entirely, which I do not want to do. Is there a special option for `shadow-exclude` that I am missing, or something else that I could do, or is this impossible to fix?

Thank you very much in advance.

PS. Here's my compton.conf file before I forget:

```
shadow-radius=10;
shadow-opacity=0.9;
shadow-offset-x=-15;
shadow-offset-y=-15;
shadow = true;
no-dock-shadow = false;
no-dnd-shadow = true;
clear-shadow = true;
inactive-dim = 0.25;
inactive-opacity = 0.9;
fading = true;
fade-delta = 5;
opacity-rule = [ "99:class_g = 'URxvt'" ];
shadow-exclude = [
    "class_g = 'Firefox' && argb",
    "name = 'ffmpeg'"
];

#Window type settings
wintypes:
{
  tooltip = { fade = true; shadow = false; };
  menu = { shadow = false; };
  dropdown_menu = { shadow = false; };
  popup_menu =  { shadow = false; };
  utility =  { shadow = false; };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `"window_type *= 'normal' && ! name ~= ''"` to the list of `shadow-exclude` fixed the problem right up! I'm pretty sure this is because the area has no WM_CLASS, and as such is now excluded from having a shadow.